# Sharepoint 2010 publishing page does not save changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I'm facing a bug - publishing page does not save changes of title field.

I go to Site Actions -> Edit Page, make changes to content fields and then I click Check In -> Publish. After refreshing the page all changes are gone.

I can only save the changes of title field from "Edit Page Setting".

In sharepoint desinger my script is like that

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">
</SharePointWebControls:TextField>
```

The problem is persistent across the entire site. Please advise.

Comment: Try using the StaticName of the field in FieldName instead of the GUID

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same problem...